# AOE Profiler not displaying in footer

Tags: magento-1.8, profiler

Have tried installing AOE Profiler on a Magento CE 1.8 site, successfully installed with Composer but despite enabling it in `index.php`, `local.xml` and the Magento backend, the profiler doesn't appear in the footer. Have refreshed caches, restarted Apache to flush APC.
No IP address specified so it's not that that is stopping it.

All to no avail, can anyone suggest how I can work out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be quite a few things, but just to get these out of the way:

- Did you run `$ modman deploy Aoe_Profiler`? (check that you have an entry for AOE Profiler in the System menu)
- Did you add "?profile=1" to the end of the url you're profiling?

Comment: Hi, I think this is appropriate to the latest version of Aoe_Profiler not the 3 branch that installed with composer. I uninstalled and used modman as you suggested and it is working in the backend.

Answer (score 12):

The latest version of AoE_Profiler does not render the profiler in the footer anymore.

You should still be able to check it in the backend via System -> AOE Profiler

Answer (score 5):

Which version of AOE Profiler are you using? version 0.4.0 wasn't to my liking either as the profiling is stored in BLOBs in the DB instead of just on screen like previous version version 0.3.0 and below.

If you are using v0.4.0 make sure you have the `aoe_profiler.xml` mentioned in the proper location and is configured properly, etc:

- https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler/blob/master/var/aoe_profiler.xml.sample

You may try that version as the versions are tagged in the github account.  Also try and use `?profiler=1` as David mentioned if it still isn't triggered then there is most likely a conflict or the footer block itself has been rewritten and the module isn't able to hook into it properly.  Try using the default theme/template temporarily to verify such is a quick easy way to tell.

...and last you may want to open an issue on github as you'll most likely get better support from the devs than here: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler/issues

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I marked the other answer as accepted because it was using modman to install that resolved my issue but I found your post useful also and upvoted you accordingly.