# Site very slow, exhausted all options. Really need assistance

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

Ok, i have come to the end of my tether on fixing the speed of my site. I have spent hours and days researching and applying all methods to get the page load speed to improve, whilst i've noticed some improvements with 90% of my extensions currently disabled it's still not how it should be.

I have a relatively high spec server - 32GB RAM, 512GB SSD drives, intel 8core cpu, apache + varnish + cloudlinux with many tweakings done to mysql, php etc

I will outline what i've done so far:

1. GZIP Compression - ON
2. Varnish on backend - ON
3. Nexcess Turpentine - ON
4. Compress CSS + JS
5. Deactivated near enough all extensions apart from whats needed
6. Use of CDN (cloudflare)
7. Optimization of images

Yet i still get a page load time of around 4.5 seconds on average.

The only thing i can think of it being is the theme? I've hit a brick wall on my limited level of expertise and always try and find out how to do fix things before posting, i've become desperate for some assistance.

Domain is: [www.modxpc.com](http://www.modxpc.com) (bear in mind many extensions are off also cdn, so the speed now should be the current "best")

#### Profiler Results (click screenshots to enlarge)

Following onto the comments regarding AOE Profile, these are the results:

[image: overview]
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/490310/mfpas7yfre5etenzhheo

I've sorted it from the highest time, i see a lot of time is being taken up by catalog_category_view. Where do i start with this?

[image: catalog_category_view]
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/490321/z3dg1w51t39efsn5sigb

Nearly all of my navigation has a catalogue url rewrite, would that cause this? Profiler shows left-products.phtml as the culprit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AOE Profiler not displaying in footer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67788/aoe-profiler-not-displaying-in-footer)

Comment: use aoe profiler to check performance

Comment: Thanks, i've installed it and with the screenshot i've linked up in the post, I've sorted it from the highest time, i see a lot of time is being taken up by catalog_category_view. Clicking itWhere do i start with this? Nearly all of my navigation has a catalogue url rewrite, would that cause this? [link](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/490321/z3dg1w51t39efsn5sigb) shows left-products.phtml  as the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

There is one template in the left column that loads products (probably too many, based on the memory usage) and then takes forever. **This alone is a red flag for the theme**. Without knowing more about what this template is doing, your next steps are:

1. Investigate, what `sm/basicproduts/left-products.phtml` is doing, probably some nasty loops after the product collection has been loaded.
2. Decide:

   - Optimize if you can and it's worth it
   - Remove the block/template

Comment: With this theme, they had some extensions within it already and one was "Basic Products", which i've just disabled, speed increased a tad but not much. So, i thought to switch to rwd theme and its considerably faster, but pages loading around 3 to 4 seconds as per F12 on chrome dev tools. So do you think i should simply go for another theme? Perhaps one that is coded better?

Comment: If that's an option for you, I would recommend to find a better theme and remove the extensions that came with this one, yes. There are probably more performance killers hidden in there.

Comment: Can i ask whether you think the current site is slow? It's more on clicking the links. I am looking through other templates now, just dont want the same problem to happen again.